# JSON Exception (On Post Execute not working)

Tags: android

I am quite new to Android. Previously this code was running but now it is showing `end of character at input 0 of`.I can't solve it.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{

            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
            int success =jsonResult.getInt("success");
            if(success==1)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                JSONArray students = jsonResult.getJSONArray("regicourse");
                for (int i=0; i< students.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject student= students.getJSONObject(i);
                    int rollno = student.getInt("Rollno");
                  /*  String firstname =student.getString("firstname;");
                    String lastname =student.getString("lastname;");
                    String line = rollno + "-" + firstname + "-" + lastname; */
                    String line = rollno + "  ";
                    adapter.add(line);
                    arrayList.add(rollno);


                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is no data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your json response here

Comment: post this result here

Comment: Check your json response.

Comment: how could i post my json response? in doin background i used url =         String host = "http://192.168.43.109/fetch.php?course="+courseno which gives the result {"success":1,"regicourse":[{"id":"5","Courseno":"CSE3202","Rollno":"1507002"},{"id":"9","Courseno":"CSE3202","Rollno":"1507020"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can do log.i(result) as the first line of your function.

At the first glance, this has a trouble:

```
int rollno = student.getInt("Rollno");
```

it is string so you should call

```
String rollno = student.getString("Rollno");
```

Comment: previously it was working with int rollno = student.getInt("Rollno"); I have tried your one too. But couldn't solve it

Comment: you can do e.printStack() to know which line is throwing exception.

Comment: nothing is showing. But what might be the cause as same code working previously,not now?